# Error al importar hoja de estilo en pagina html

Tags: html5, css3

Intento enlazar mi css externo al html, pero no me resulta, es decir, no carga el estilo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sugiero para las próximas preguntas, copies el código directamente en lugar de una imagen, es difícil tratar de reproducir el error de esa manera, la imagen debería ser únicamente para representar la estructura de directorios.

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imagenes con código. Edita tu pregunta y coloca directamente el código como texto en ella. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

La ruta está mal, como tu archivo `index.html` y la carpeta `estilo` están en el mismo directorio, solo basta con esta ruta: `estilo/style.css`.

La puedes usar así:

```
<link rel="style" href="estilo/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que en el link estás subiendo un nivel, o sea, le ponés .. y va a buscar el css en la carpeta al mismo nivel que la carpeta CODE.  Ten en cuenta que el href es relativo a la ubicación de tu HTML.

Prueba ponerlo así, debería funcionar:

```
<link rel="style" href="estilo/style.css">
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por sus comentarios: hice lo que me sugirieron, pero no funciona aun: pego un pantallazo con vista al inspector

saludos y gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]